# any example for using Arquillian with hibernate and embedded-tomcat 7

Tags: hibernate, tomcat7, jboss-arquillian

I am setting Arquillian with CDI , hibernate and tomcat-embedded 7.
I could find a few example for CDI and tomcat-embedded 7 and it is working fine with my Arquillian tests, but I couldn't find any resources or example for setting Arquillian with hibernate and tomcat-embedded. (samples for setting data source , persistence.xml, shrinkWrap )

I will appriciate anything in this regard ( example , URL , blog, source code).

The only thing which I could find for tomcat and Arquillian is this URL https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-tomcat/ , but there is nothing related to JPA (hibernate) settings in these examples

Comment: I'm not sure what you would expect to see.  Hibernate is a library that you would need to include, so when you're building your archive via ShrinkWrap just include the hibernate libraries as a dependency.

Comment: @John Ament  - I would like to see a working example for Atquillian with CDI, Hibernate and Tomcat-embedded like any other written examples for other containers like glassfish. I would like to inject my entityManager in my testcase running on tomcat-embedded. I want to know how many resource file we should introduce in our shrinkWrap and how (persistence.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml, web.xml, context.xml, beans.xml and ...) and Listeners to startup JPA (hibernate) and any other things which may I missed.

Comment: And I'm assuming that when you take the glassfish example, it doesn't work for tomcat embedded?

Comment: NO. We need much more setting than glassfish, since we are not using a java EE container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to setup an Arquillian project with Hibernate, Weld CDI, H2 embedded database on embedded-tomcat 7. Here is the link on Github https://github.com/Yasharbi/Arquillian-TomcatEmbedded-Hibernate-CDI-H2.git